# Android creating text file

Tags: android

I want to create/write new files on the device. 
I am able to create file on sd card of the android device.

But in case if device is not having sd card then where should i create file which can be accessible from the ddms.

I tried to create it in /data/data/com.abc.app/files/ directory, But i don't have permissions to access this directory from the ddms to save the file on pc.

Which is the best location create new file on the device which can be access from ddms and application.

Comment: btw, question topic doesn't describe the aim of problem. Maybe you should correct it

Answer (score 1):

Try use cache dir local and external.

Here is a part of my code

```
File dir = context.getExternalCacheDir() != null ? 
    context.getExternalCacheDir() : context.getCacheDir();

File file = new File(dir, ".cachefile");//hidden

if (file.exists())
    file.delete();

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

//..

out.flush();
out.close();
```

Don't forget to have permissions read/write;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you have the permission to write/read in/from that folder through your applicatin. You have to use  the pair `openFileInput`/`openFileOutput`

here the doc per [openFileInput](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29)/[openFileOutput](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)